# B1ServiceLayer - get user behind SSO login

Tags: sapb1, service-layer

we are working in a CloudControlCenter environment. Now have to login with the SAP Business One SSO (Single Sign On) over Active Directory.

So for example we do following requests:

POST https://hana:50000/b1s/v1/Login

```
{
"UserName": "rz-nag\\02939106",
"Password": "Start123",
"CompanyDB": "C204651_01_DEMO_SYSONE" 
}
```

Now we are successfully logged in.

How can we get the SAP internal user for the ad-account "rz-nag\02939106"?

GET https://hana:50000/b1s/v1/Users has no field for this reference...

I checked service layer documentation

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Based on the information in the Service Layer Metadata, it appears that you should be able to retrieve the WindowsUser property from the UserActionRecord Collection.

Although I don't have an SSO or Cloud system available for testing, I found that using the GET /b1s/v1/Users(1) endpoint allows me to obtain the UserActions along with the WindowsUser information.

It's unfortunate that accessing this field directly from the object itself is not straightforward, but this limitation is also present in the DI API.

If this solution doesn't meet your requirements, you can consider using a view to expose the desired field.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.